# How to fix this parabola regression sot that the regression graph is smooth?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

```
import math
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
x = np.array([[i] for i in range(-5 , 5)])
x1 = x ** 2
y = [7 , 5 , 4 , 3 , 1 , 0 , -1  ,2 , 5 , 6]
lr = LinearRegression().fit(x1 , y)
plt.scatter(x , y)
predictions = lr.predict(x1)
plt.plot(x , predictions)
plt.show()
```

The x and y lists can be changed, but the main problem is the graph is not smooth, and I also don't get the prediction part, can anyone help?

Comment: To make the graph smoother you need more points. What don't you get about the prediction part?

Comment: how can I add more dots using linspace, because it would say that the the dimensions are wrong. and for the prediction part, what does the prediction do. and for the lr part, does the lr codes change after it fits the x and y?